# Выборка из SQL возвращает лишние скобки

Tags: python, sql

Делаю выборку из SQL

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT FL_ARCHIVE FROM ROUTE WHERE FL_ARCHIVE >= 10")
select_results = cur.fetchall()
for result in select_results:
    print result
```

Потом для каждого элемента выборки равного к примеру десяти хочу запускать определенную функцию. Проблема в том, что из БД мне не 10 вовзращается, а

```
(10,)
(10,)
(11,)
```

Я конечно понимаю, что все лишнее можно выкусить, но наверно я что-то не так делаю, если такой результат получается.

Кстати, вот 10 это будет строкой или числом? Т.е. мне надо писать

```
if result == '10':
```

или могу:

```
if result == 10:
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы вызываете fetchall() , поэтому Вам возвращается кортеж. Делайте срез на первый элемент.

```
print result[0]
```

`if result == '10':` и `if result == 10:` разные сравнения. Лучше перед сравнением приводите к ожидаемому типу через `str(result[0])` , например . Хотя в вашем случае возвращается именно тип int .

Comment: Так я вроде бы по кортежу хожу циклом for
for result in select_results:
так что все нормально должно быть...

И я так и не понял, почему у меня скобки появляются лишние при выборке...

Comment: cur.fetchall() всегда возвращает кортеж.

Comment: SELECT FL_ARCHIVE  * возможно возвращает список.